# Moving controls from Manipulate to a Palette ( or similar GUI object )

Tags: programming, dynamic, manipulate, gui-construction

Consider the following snippet as a reference.

```
 DynamicModule[{}, 
  Manipulate[
   Graphics[
     Translate[
       GeometricTransformation[
         { Blue, 
           Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
         }, {{scx, 0}, {0, scy}}
       ], 
       Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1
     ], 
     ImageSize -> 400 {1, 1}
   ], 
   {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}, 
   {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}, 
   {{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}, 
   {{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A graphical drawing program with a lot of controls (buttons, sliders) would benefit (a lot) by freeing up space and moving controls to a `Palette`, or a similar construct. I am considering the redesign of a GUI and I am currently investigating the options and technical possibilities. - Looking at the reference code snippet (which is not the GUI in question, but makes asking the question - and answering! - so much easier) I have the following question. **Is it possible to move (one of) the sliders to a `Palette`, or similar construct?**

Comment: According to @Yoda, these problems can be solved with a hardware upgrade http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4922520#4922520

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the "wormhole" construct from "tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality" like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Translate[
   GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, 
      scy}}], Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1], 
  ImageSize -> 400 {1, 1}],
 OpenerView[{Button["external",
    CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{}, Column[{
        Control[{{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}],
        Control[{{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}],
        Control[{{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}],
        Control[{{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]
        }], InheritScope -> True]
     ]],
   Column[{
     Control[{{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}],
     Control[{{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}],
     Control[{{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}],
     Control[{{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]
     }]}]

 ]
```

Comment: +1 was just about to write that. Well, at least I can go to bed 20 min earlier than I would have gone otherwise:)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
scx = scy = wi = he = 1;

CreateDocument@
  Dynamic@Graphics[
    Translate[
     GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
       Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, 
        scy}}], Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1], 
    ImageSize -> 400 {1, 1}];

CreatePalette[
  Grid[
   {
    {"x scale", Slider[Dynamic[scx], {0, 1}]},
    {"y scale", Slider[Dynamic[scy], {0, 1}]},
    {"width", Slider[Dynamic[wi], {1, 5, 1}]},
    {"heigth", Slider[Dynamic[he], {1, 5, 1}]}
    }
   ]
  ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When I delete the palette the SaveDialog appears, is that expected behavior for a Palette? ( Albert Refey's answer has a show/unshow button. ) - How do you merit your solution against the CreateDialog answer?

Comment: @ndroock1 From [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html): *CreatePalette[expr] creates an unsaved palette notebook containing expr and opens it in a separate window. To save the palette, close the window and save the file when the save dialog appears or save the palette notebook programmatically using NotebookSave.* You asked for a Palette and you got one ;-).

Comment: @ Sjoerd, Yep, a palette I got. And it's good its documented here how to create one. I am not entirely sure which way to go yet though.

Comment: @ndroock1 Note that this wasn't a citation from the CreatePalette help page itself, but from the tutorial. So, upon first reading, the appearance of the Save dialog box isn't very obvious indeed.