# What it is the best way to enforce that only one CreateDialog window can be created?

Tags: programming, gui-construction

Background. See question [Moving controls from Manipulate to a Palette ( or similar GUI object )](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6696/moving-controls-from-manipulate-to-a-palette-or-similar-gui-object). As suggested in the answer to this question I use a CreateDialog window to group and handle controls and added WindowFloating->True as an option. Clicking a second time on the external button creates an identical copy of the Window.

Question: **What it is the best way to enforce that only one CreateDialog window can be created?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest that comes to mind is to close it before opening it again.

So, where you had the `CreateDialog[...]` line, you now put `NotebookClose[nb]; nb=CreateDialog[...]`

(You can wrap your button in `DynamicModule[{nb}, Button[...]` to localize the symbol)

A better one, is to put `If[FreeQ[Notebooks[], nb], nb=CreateDialog[...]]`

Here's the tweaked code taken from the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6697/109) by @AlbertRetey

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Translate[
   GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
    {{scx, 0}, {0, scy}}],
   Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1], ImageSize -> 400 {1, 1}],
 OpenerView[{DynamicModule[{nb},
    Button["external",
     If[FreeQ[Notebooks[], nb],
      nb = CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{},
         Column[{Control[{{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}], 
           Control[{{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}],
           Control[{{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}],
           Control[{{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]}],
         InheritScope -> True]]];SetSelectedNotebook[nb]],
Deinitialization :> (NotebookClose[nb])],
   Column[{Control[{{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}],
     Control[{{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}],
     Control[{{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}],
     Control[{{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]}]}]]
```

Comment: thanks for citing me :-). You might want to add `SetSelectedNotebook[nb]` in the else part of the `If`. Another obvious problem with this (well, my) code is that the dialog will stay open when the `Manipulate` is removed (or overwritten with the next evaluation). I couldn't get a naive `Deinitialization` for the `DynamicModule[{nb},...]` to work, though...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, just edited with your suggestions. The `Deinitialization` doesn't seem to be instantaneous, but it closes the dialog as soon as I type something else in a notebook

Comment: o.k., very good to know, thanks for that information, Mathematica keeps us all busy with learning new facts :-). Closing the window when the next such `Manipulate` will be generated is the best I could manage to do with other approaches up to now. So the `Deinitialization` seems to be the best approach known to me so far. I really wonder if it would be possible to make it "instantaneous", though...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I wonder what exactly does this mean: *Deinitialization will never be performed unless initialization has previously been performed.*

Comment: you seem to read what I do, wonder, wonder :-). I guess this wants to tell us that the deinitialization can safely assume that the initialization, if given, has been done before the deinitialization will be done. I was wondering whether: *Deinitialization may be delayed if, for example, a construct appears in an invisible location such as the clipboard.* is an explanation for the delayed `NotebookClose`. We do show dynamic-module variables in that window that do belong to the manipulate we just deleted, so maybe that's the reason ?!?

Comment: The issues with `Deinitialization` timing were just stupid bugs.  Which, I believe, are now all fixed in v10.  But I don't think the statement about deinitialization only being performed if initialization has been performed is that mysterious.  As you know, dynamics may never evaluate.  E.g., if they're never scrolled onscreen, or forever live inside of a closed cell group, they might never get resolved.  Which means they would never get initialized.  Which, the documentation is explaining, means they would never get deinitialized.

Comment: @JohnFultz good to know, thanks for fixing it. I look forward to trying v10 soon